# How does the projection_output affect the attention vector size in tensorflow embedding attention seq2seq

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

As the title,

there is a warning in the official site that "Warning: when output_projection is None, the size of the attention vectors and variables will be made proportional to num_decoder_symbols, can be large."

I don't know why the output projection could have effect on attention vector size.

In fact, I read the source code about the embedding attention size.

In my view, the attention mechanism is computed based on the cell output, and there is no projection operate on the cell output before used by attention. So, how could the output projection affect the attention vector size?

Thanks very much and beg for some explanation...

Answer (score 1):

You're right to say: " the attention mechanism is computed based on the cell output". But in case there is no projection (output_projection is None) the cell output must have the same dimension as num_output_symbols to allow decoding. This is forced by the OutputProjectionWrapper in this line. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L866 So now the cell output has potentially very large dimensionality, which makes it not well-suited for attention. As you can see one line above, this only happens if output_projection is None, otherwise all is fine and the projection is used.

Comment: yep, I see that the output projection could affect the output size. but, when the attention state generate, you can see this line, [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L859), it uses the cell.output size before projection operation. Therefore, in my opinion, the attention state size doesn't change by the output projection. I'm not sure if I was right.